# Recording audio while button is held down

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation

I'm wondering what is the best way for me to record sound while the user is holding down a UIButton. (i.e. start when the user is holding down and stop when he releases the button). Will something like this work?

Function call

```
button.addTarget(self, action: "holding:", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
```

Function:

```
func holding (sender:UIButton!) {

// Sound recording code here

}
```

Also I'm trying to update a UIProgressView as the sound is recorded. Is there a way I can access the amount of time (in seconds / milliseconds) that has elapsed since the recording has started? Can I just use my own timer or will there be some dependency?

Comment: Where do you want to access the elapsed time? And, yes you can do something like you have, and you can stop the recording in another method on the same button that's called on TouchUpInside.

Comment: I want to access it from within the `holding` function, so that I can update a `UIProgressView` from its tag

Comment: Then yes, you can use a timer that you start in the holding method, and that you invalidate in the method that's called on touch up inside.

Comment: Look at `UIControlEvents` and you'll find events for `TouchUpInside` and `TouchUpOutside` as well as `TouchDown`  Don't forget to handle the `TouchCancel` case as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement recently, and instead of using a `UIButton` I used a regular view (`UILabel`,`UIImageView` or whatever you want the 'button' to look like) with a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` added. The gesture recognizer's target function can then stop/start recording as needed:

```
func holding (sender:UILongPressGestureRecognizer!) {

    // If the gesture state is UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan start recording

    // If it is UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded stop recording

}
```